# iOS : How to turn on Auto-Brightness programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, brightness, screen-brightness

My question is the opposite of this one : [How to turn off Auto-Brightness programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782700/how-to-turn-off-auto-brightness-programmatically)

When I set a custom screen brightness like that : 
`UIScreen.main.brightness = 0.1`, it disable the system auto brightness. To re-enable it, we have to lock and to unlock the phone. Is there any simple way to programmatically go back to automatic mode ?

Please note that I don't want to only back to the previous brightness level in "manual" mode like that :

```
if let previous = self.previousBrightness { UIScreen.main.brightness = previous }
```

If the ambient luminosity change in the meantime, that's not a great solution.

I imagine something like that :

```
UIScreen.main.brightnessMode = .auto
```

Comment: the answer is the same.  You can not manage general settings from the app

Comment: Thanks m1sh0 ! But editing the `UIScreen.main.brightness` property act like to disable auto mode. I wonder if there is any way to "revert" this property edition which seems to deactivate the system brightness management